# what is the fastest way to insert row in two table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two mysql tables and I want to insert an email in both of them.

I need to split email to `name` and `domain name` and insert each part of them to one table.

My `domain` table is like this:

```
+----+--------+
| id | domain | primary(id)
+----+--------+
```

and my `email` table is:

```
+-------+----------+
| eMail | domainId | primary key(eMail, domainId)
+-------+----------+
```

i.e: info@example.com > `example.com` have to insert in `domain` table and
`info` have to add in `email` table with domainId.

domain must be unique.

My try:

```
foreach($emails as $email)
{
    list($account,$hostname) = explode('@',$email,2);

    $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM domain WHERE domain LIKE :domain LIMIT 0,1");
    $query->execute(array(':domain'=>trim($hostname)));

    if($query->rowCount())
    {
        $id = $query->fetch();
        $id = $id['id'];
    }else{
        $insert = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO domain (domain) VALUES (:domain)");
        $insert->execute(array(':domain'=>trim($hostname)));
        $id = $dbh->lastInsertId();
    }

    $name = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO email (eMail, domainId) VALUES (:eMail, :domainId)");
    $name->execute(array(':eMail'=>trim($account),':domainId'=>$id));
}
```

but this way is very slow when I want to add bulk emails:

Is there any faster way or maybe I can do this in single query..?

Comment: Only insert the emails and add a trigger that that table that extracts the domain name and inserts that automatically into `domains`

Comment: then there is a better way. but how to add a trigger?

Comment: how many emails & how many domains are there? are there a lot of emails from the same domain?

Comment: yes, most of them are from the same domain. but not always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have a lot of emails from the same domain, you can try caching the domain ids in a local php variable in order to reduce the # of queries to the db.

Also, you should prepare the `$insert` and `$name` statements just once outside your loop.

```
$domains = array();

foreach($dbh->query("SELECT id, domain FROM domain") as $domain) {
    $domains[$domain['domain']] = $domain['id'];
}

$insert = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO domain (domain) VALUES (:domain)");
$name = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO email (eMail, domainId) VALUES (:eMail,:domainId)");

foreach($emails as $email)
{
    list($account,$hostname) = explode('@',$email,2);
    $hostname = trim($hostname);

    if(!isset($domains[$hostname])) {
        $insert->execute(array(':domain'=>$hostname));
        $id = $dbh->lastInsertId();
        $domains[$hostname] = $id;
    }
    else {
        $id = $domains[$hostname];
    }    

    $name->execute(array(':eMail'=>trim($account),':domainId'=>$id));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Only insert the emails and add a trigger to the `email` table that extracts the domain name and inserts that automatically into `domain`

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER insert_domain_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON email 
FOR EACH ROW 
begin
  set @domainname = substring(NEW.email, instr(NEW.email, '@') + 1);
  if(select count(*) from domain where domain = @domainname) = 0
  then
     insert into domain (domain) values (@domainname);
  end if;
end
|
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a simple procedure could fix this?

This would need the field domain in the database to be of type `UNIQUE` for the `INSERT IGNORE INTO` syntax.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_InsertEmail`(IN p_Email VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN

-- Declare variables
DECLARE v_Email VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE v_Domain VARCHAR(100);

-- Set the variables
SET v_Email = SUBSTRING(p_Email,1,INSTR(p_email,'@')-1);
SET v_Domain =SUBSTRING(p_Email,INSTR(p_Email,'@'));

-- Now insert ignore into domain table

INSERT IGNORE INTO db.domain (domain) VALUES(v_Domain);

-- Then insert like this.

INSERT IGNORE INTO db.email SELECT v_Email,DomainId FROM domain WHERE domain=v_Domain;

END
```

Then simply call the procedure

```
CALL db.sp_InsertEmail('name@domain.com')
```